# How can I disable the M-h keybinding in org-mode with evil-mode?

Tags: key-bindings, evil

The problem seems to be that `evil-mode` translates the key chord `M-<left>` into `M-h`. Unsetting `M-h` by binding it to `nil` in the local, global or `org-mode` map in a `org-mode` hook does not help.

Comment: Is it bound in an evil-mode keymap? If so, consider unbinding it there.

Comment: I don't know where it is bound. How can I figure it out? As I said, I suspect that `evil-mode` creates a binding `M-h` matching `M-<left>` because `h` is essentially the left arrow key in VIM.

Comment: Look in the evil source code. Or just try `evil-mode-map` or something. Or wait till someone here points you in the right direction. It's also possible that Evil uses its own special functions to create or change key bindings...

Comment: I'd refrain from such wild guesses until I've verified they're true, like by pasting the output of `F1 k M-<left>`.

Comment: `<M-left> runs the command org-metaleft (found in org-mode-map)`, `M-h runs the command org-metaleft`. I tried unbinding it from all evil state maps and `spacemacs-org-mode-map`. I also tried listing all maps that contain `(kbd "M-h")` but it's only `diff-mode-map` which is unrelated. So does evil perhaps dynamically remap `<left>` to `h`, not via a key map?

Comment: I'm having the same problem for M-{h,j,k,l}. Would love to find out what is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this too. I have a custom minor mode that I used for defining keys but all my keybindings were getting overwritten by org mode. I tried unbinding the M-{j,k,h,l} keys from org-mode specifically and even disabling all keybindings in org mode but nothing worked. M-h was still running the function to demote the header.

It ended up being the evil-collection package I was using. The dumb fix (which i don't mind) is to only enable evil-collection for the modes I want to use it in. You'd have to google how to disable keybinds from that package.

I'm okay with not using it in org mode. This is how I'm loading evil-collection now

```
   (use-package evil-collection
   :after evil
   :ensure t
   :config
  (evil-collection-init
   '(dired-mode ibuffer-mode))
   )
```